# Snap circle to a polyline in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a polyline in leaflet on which I want to snap center a circle with which I want to move among the polyline so the circle is always at the center of the polyline.

[image: Circle on polyline]

Is there a way how to snap center of circle into center so when I move the circle it always centers on the polyline?

Comment: How to you want to move circle?

Comment: When you hold the circle (by mouse, touch gesture) anywhere, it should travel on the polyline the way you move the circle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a fiddle, where the circle is moved just on `mousemove` event: http://jsfiddle.net/v0bseuqz/32/

The main idea is to create a line (when mouse is moved) that strokes cursor coordinates from the top of the map to the bottom, and check if it intersects the polyline to which the circle should be snapped. It they intersect, their intersection should be new centre of the circle.

```
document.onload = loadMap();

function loadMap() {
  var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 12);
  L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpandmbXliNDBjZWd2M2x6bDk3c2ZtOTkifQ._QA7i5Mpkd_m30IGElHziw', {   
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox.streets',
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZW======V6ZTdlb2V5cyJ9.3HqHQ4BMRvSPaYe8ToA7YQ'
  }).addTo(map);

    L.polyline([
            [-50, 1000],
      [0, 0]
        ], {
        color: 'red',
      weight: 1
    }).addTo(map);

  var circle = L.circle([0, 0], 500, {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
    }).addTo(map);

  $( "#map" ).mousemove(function( event ) {  
    var cursorPoint = new L.Point(event.clientX, event.clientY);
    var cursorLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(cursorPoint);
    var intersection = (checkLineIntersection(0, 0, 1000, -50, cursorLatLng.lng, 1, cursorLatLng.lng, -1));
    if (intersection.onLine1 && intersection.onLine2) {
        circle.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(intersection.y, intersection.x));
    }
});

}


function checkLineIntersection(line1StartX, line1StartY, line1EndX, line1EndY, line2StartX, line2StartY, line2EndX, line2EndY) {
    // if the lines intersect, the result contains the x and y of the intersection (treating the lines as infinite) and booleans for whether line segment 1 or line segment 2 contain the point
    var denominator, a, b, numerator1, numerator2, result = {
        x: null,
        y: null,
        onLine1: false,
        onLine2: false
    };
    denominator = ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * (line1EndX - line1StartX)) - ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
    if (denominator == 0) {
        return result;
    }
    a = line1StartY - line2StartY;
    b = line1StartX - line2StartX;
    numerator1 = ((line2EndX - line2StartX) * a) - ((line2EndY - line2StartY) * b);
    numerator2 = ((line1EndX - line1StartX) * a) - ((line1EndY - line1StartY) * b);
    a = numerator1 / denominator;
    b = numerator2 / denominator;

    // if we cast these lines infinitely in both directions, they intersect here:
    result.x = line1StartX + (a * (line1EndX - line1StartX));
    result.y = line1StartY + (a * (line1EndY - line1StartY));
/*
        // it is worth noting that this should be the same as:
        x = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndX - line2StartX));
        y = line2StartX + (b * (line2EndY - line2StartY));
        */
    // if line1 is a segment and line2 is infinite, they intersect if:
    if (a > 0 && a < 1) {
        result.onLine1 = true;
    }
    // if line2 is a segment and line1 is infinite, they intersect if:
    if (b > 0 && b < 1) {
        result.onLine2 = true;
    }
    // if line1 and line2 are segments, they intersect if both of the above are true
    return result;
};
```

**UPDATE**

If you have a polyline that is defined by more than two points, you should check intersection of it's every segment with the perpendicular line. Jut do it in a loop. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v0bseuqz/39/

```
var coords = [
  [0.003, 0.080],
  [-0.008, 0.041],
  [0, 0]
];
L.polyline(coords, {
  color: 'red',
  weight: 1
}).addTo(map);

var circle = L.circle([0, 0], 500, {
  color: 'red',
  fillColor: '#f03',
  fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map);
var startY, startX, endY, endX, cursorPoint, cursorLatLng, intersection;
$( "#map" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  for(i = coords.length, i >0; i--;) {
    if (i - 1 >= 0) {
     startY = coords[i][0];
     startX = coords[i][1];
     endY = coords[i - 1][0];
     endX = coords[i - 1][1];

     cursorPoint = new L.Point(event.clientX, event.clientY);
     cursorLatLng = map.containerPointToLatLng(cursorPoint);
     intersection = (checkLineIntersection(startX, startY, endX, endY, cursorLatLng.lng, 1, cursorLatLng.lng, -1));
     if (intersection.onLine1 && intersection.onLine2) {
       circle.setLatLng(new L.LatLng(intersection.y, intersection.x));
     }
   }
 }
```

});

I've taken the algorithm of detecting the intersection of two lines [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Gd2S2/113/)

Comment: This works for 2 points on a polyline.

Let's say I have n points of polylines, is that possible, too?

Comment: Do it in a loop, for every segment (defined by each two points) of the polyline.

Comment: Sure, here you go! Check my answer, I've updated it. Please, next time be more specific in original post. It would be even better if you will provide some code that you've tried, but if you will attach a fiddle, that'll be fabulous! :)

Comment: I'm trying to make this working on a touch device. I have the circle that I want to be moving the opposite direction than the gesture is. Is there a way to done that?